# How DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain refresh the aws client token?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-iot

I am creating AmazonS3Client using DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.
Inside this, I have used WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider which is internally calling STSProfileCredentialsServiceLoader.
My question is, in the case when the token is refreshed, how AmazonS3Client automatically get to know about it and uses the new credentials?  Once the bean(AmazonS3Client) is created, how the tokens are refreshed and reflected back to the already instantiated bean? Is there any implementation that is modifying the AmazonS3Client? I am unable to get the code flow between AmazonS3Client and AWSCredentialsProvider. Can someone help me to understand that?

Also is there any way to achieve the same(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain) using any custom implementation while creating AWSIotMqttClient bean?

I am using java-spring-boot for building the application.

Answer (score 0):

The AmazonS3Client has a [reference to the credential provider](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/95aa0b7719d83e050ba9a31622add2e5f685f777/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L451). When it needs to make a request, it will [sign it using the credentials provided](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/95aa0b7719d83e050ba9a31622add2e5f685f777/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L4383-L4384) by the WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider (in your case). As long as this provider refreshes its credentials before the last ones expire, the client will always have a reference to valid credentials.

Not sure if this is what you mean, but most constructors taking in AWS IAM tokens as a parameter are deprecated in favor of using a CredentialsProvider [like so](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/blob/32facbab00eaf77c0367e58319a94d1b062ed40a/aws-iot-device-sdk-java/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/iot/client/AWSIotMqttClient.java#L305-L307).

Comment: This make sense. But I have follow-up question to this. How WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider gets to know the token is expired and it needs to refresh. Does it internally have some refresh listener which continuously checks the credentials validity. Where is that implementation?

Comment: It actually seems like the WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider doesn't have a refresh implementation, and just gives static credentials.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/95aa0b7719d83e050ba9a31622add2e5f685f777/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.java#L80-L82

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html#refresh--

Comment: But it internally uses STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider which has refresh implementation. How does this class knows about the token expiry?

Comment: You're right, the default WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider just wraps STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider, which contains a ProfileCredentialsService vending another CredentialsProvider. This is the one with the actual refresh handling. It contains a [RefreshableTask](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-sts/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/RefreshableTask.java) which starts a thread that keeps track of [the expiry time](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-sts/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/ShouldDoAsyncSessionRefresh.java) and refreshes.